# How to find the sub-array in a array with maximum xor?

Tags: c++, c, logic, max, xor

Given an array suppose

```
Arr[]={1,2,3}
```

I want to find the maximum-sum sub array.
e.g.: For above case `A[]={1,2,3}`
    Answer is : `3` `(1 xor 2)` or `(3)`

Comment: is it PHP, java, javascript or? can you tell more about this?

Comment: I need it in c++, or enough if u give pseudo code

Comment: suppose if we want to find two subarrays,what should we do?